# Missing Vtable when linking .o files

Tags: c++, linker, vtable

I am writing a simple server program using ICE by ZeroC. When I try to link the .o files it gave me the following error message:

```
$ c++ -o server UserMap.o Server.o -L/Library/Developer/Ice-3.5.0/lib -lIce -lIceUtil
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "VTT for UserMapI", referenced from:
      UserMapI::UserMapI() in Server.o
  "vtable for UserMapI", referenced from:
      UserMapI::UserMapI() in Server.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

After some googling I understand that the problem is I have an abstract class with 3 virtual methods declared in `UserMap.ice` (and hence in `UserMap.h` and `UserMap.cpp` generated by the command `slice2cpp UserMap.ice`), and in `Server.cpp` I have a class called `UserMapI:public UserMap` which implements the three virtual methods and another private helper function. The error is generated because the compiler thinks I have declared all functions(methods) in `UserMap.h` and `UserMap.cpp`.

My understanding to this problem is that I should modify the link command so that the linker will know that there are more functions in `UserMapI` declared in `Server.cpp`, but I don't have enough knowledge to do the modification. Can someone help me please?

Thank you all.

---

Here is the compiler command I am using to get `Server.o` and `UserMap.o`:

```
c++ -I. -I/Library/Developer/Ice-3.5.0/include -c UserMap.cpp Server.cpp
```

---

Here's the code of `UserMap.ice`:

```
module DR
{
    class UserMap
    {
        void addUserToLocation(int userID, int x, int y);
        string getUsersNearLocation(int x, int y, int distance);
        void removeFromMap(int userID, int x, int y);
    };
};
```

`slice2cpp` command slices this `.ice` file into a `.h` and a `.cpp` file that works as an API between server and client.

In `Server.cpp` I have the following include:

```
#include <Ice/Ice.h>
#include "UserMap.h"

#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
```

and the following subclass:

```
class UserMapI : public UserMap
{
public:
    virtual void addUserToLocation(int userID, int x, int y, const Ice::Current &);
    virtual string getUsersNearLocation(int x, int y, int distance, const Ice::Current &);
    virtual void removeFromMap(int userID, int x, int y, const Ice::Current &);
private:
    string stringify(int x, int y);
};
```

And after implementing all methods here's the `main` function:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int status = 0;
    Ice::CommunicatorPtr ic;
    try {
        ic = Ice::initialize(argc, argv);
        Ice::ObjectAdapterPtr adapter = ic->createObjectAdapterWithEndpoints("SimpleUserMapAdapter", "default -p 10000");
        Ice::ObjectPtr object = new UserMapI;
        adapter->add(object, ic->stringToIdentity("SimpleUserMap"));
        adapter->activate();
        ic->waitForShutdown();
    } catch (const Ice::Exception & e) {
        cerr << e << endl;
        status = 1;
    } catch (const char * msg) {
        cerr << msg << endl;
        status = 1;
    }
    if (ic){
        try {
            ic->destroy();
        } catch (const Ice::Exception & e) {
            cerr << e << endl;
            status = 1;
        }
    }
    return status;
}
```

---

Here's the [`UserMap.h`](https://github.com/oxrider/DR-for-help/blob/master/Documents/TryDRServer/UserMap.h).

Comment: Can you post the code. Only the structure will be helpful

Comment: I have posted some of the code. I hope that this will help.

Comment: I am not entirely sure of this but as I see you inherit from `UserMapI` from `userMap` class and `userMap` class does not have those functions as virtual.

Comment: ya the userMap class is defined in a `.ice` file, it is then sliced into a `.h` and a `.cpp` file. The slicing creates internet friendly api and all methods in the `.h` and `.cpp` are then virtual. Basically the resultant `UserMap.cpp` has those functions as virtual.

Comment: Can you show what the generated `UserMap.h` looks like?

Comment: I wish I could but it is too long to be posted here. Is there a place I could post the code other than pastebin.com? I can't access pastebin from China. T_T

Comment: @greatwolf Here's the link to the [file](https://github.com/oxrider/DR-for-help/blob/master/Documents/TryDRServer/UserMap.h).

Comment: There seems to be several `UserMap` classes in differing namespaces. Which one does your `UserMapI` inherit from?